# Net.exe use 'Error: A command was used with conflicting switches.' while using /savecred

Tags: networking, windows-services, command-prompt, drive-mapping

I am trying to use following command to map a drive in persistent mode, and I don't want it to ask login credentials everytime I reboot the machine:

```
net use P: \\server\folder Password123 /user:user123 /savecred /persistent:yes
```

But I am getting folowing error:

```
A command was used with conflicting switches.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3510.
```

I followed this article: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/net-use-command.htm

Please help with this issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When we use `/savecred` switch we should not give the credentials in the same line. The correct command should be:

```
net use P: \\server\folder /savecred /persistent:yes
```

It will ask for username and password.

Comment: The help doesn't give any indication of this at all :/  It's worth noting if you have credentials in the vault already, the command line won't ask you for them.

Comment: This doesn't ask for a password for me, it just announces success and a "dir p:" gives "access is denied".

Answer (score 24):

You can add your credentials to Windows Vault and then map you drive, this way you can avoid the limitation sabertooth1990 mentioned:

```
CMDKEY /add:%server% /user:%username% /pass:%password%
NET USE \\%server%\%folder% %localdrive% /SAVECRED /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: +1 for letting me know about the poorly named `cmdkey` command (really Microsoft?). Also note that if you use this command first, there's no need to pass /SAVECRED to `net use`. /SAVECRED really means "use current credentials, but if they don't work, ask me for credentials and save them in Credential Manager".