# net use with /savecred is not working in PowerShell remote

Tags: powershell, persistent, powershell-remoting, net-use, drive-mapping

I am trying to permanently map a drive on XP computer (has instaled PS V2) over a PowerShell Remote session with a admin privileges.
I tried this advice: [Net.exe use 'Error: A command was used with conflicting switches.' while using /savecred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996846/net-exe-use-error-a-command-was-used-with-conflicting-switches-while-using)

```
[zikaz-7]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> net use V: \\CNBS-Test\Storage
/savecred /P:yes
```

and I get this error instead of being asked for username and pass:

```
The password is invalid for \CNBS-Test\Storage.Enter the user name for 
'CNBS-Test': net.exe....The operation was canceled by the user.
```

and when I try like this:

```
[zikaz-7]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> net use V: \\CNBS-Test\storage
/persistent:yes /savecred /user:domain2003\admistrator admin123
```

I get "A command was used with conflicting switches" error becouse of /user and /savecred.

I can map whitout /savecred but it only last until reboot.
I tried bouth of them without /persisten but get the same resoult, and I looked on every forum I could fined and everywhere they said one of those two examples.
How do I solve this problem, am I writeing something wrong in the first example or that can not work over PS remote session? Or do I have to import -credential and then /savecred on that, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a variation on the [double-hop problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2009/06/25/9803001.aspx) - From computer A, you remotely execute something on computer B, which tries to access computer C.

You can get around this by using Cred-SSP; [special steps](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d86d7815-2d3a-43ae-95bd-5f4ebad3f263/howto-enable-credssp-on-xpsp3) may be required on the XP machine.

Comment: Tnx for the answer but, i already did all that before, so i could access a second computer and map a drive located on a third one. The only problem is that I can not map it with /savecred, and it's working without it. 
It wouldn't be possible to map a drive on a third computer at all if i didn't do those steps right, but I could be wrong ofc, am I??